# Upgraded Smartedit from 2011 to 2105 but now facing issue in custom functionality loading

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, hybris-data-hub, smartedit

Upgraded Smartedit from 2011 to 2105 but now custom modules loads first and out of the box modules loads after and overrides the functionality. In 2011 there was one option to add the application.* configuration in which we used to define how custom module extends out of the box, but now in 2105 that is not valid anymore. So how we can change this loading order. Because if I add any custom service which need to replace the out of the box service so it is not replacing it.

Tried adding my service in providers array of my module customsmarteditcontainer.ts and also provided the @GatewayProxied() on top of the service as well.